# How did Kirito bring back Yui when she was deleted by Cardinal SAO?

Tags: sword-art-online

How did Kirito bring back Yui when she was deleted by Cardinal SAO? I honestly don't understand this.

Comment: are we talking about the series? or is this something that happens in the movie?

Comment: This is probably a Prime example of a Duplicate question, its different but the answer is the same, though it takes a little bit of connecting the dots to figure that out.